# How to check if only one value is not null in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, razor, null

Let's say I have 3 textboxes in cshtml. What I am trying to do in Javascript is the following:

Check if ANY OF those 3 values and ONLY THEM is not null.

The only way I can think of is doing it manually:

```
if ((val1 & !val2 & !val3) || (!val1 & val2 & !val3) || (!val1 & !val2 & val3))
```

It is okay if it is a small number of textboxes, but if such number grows to 10+, it might become a hassle.

**Is there any efficient way to implement such logic in Javascript regardless of how many textboxes we are dealing with?**

Comment: Why would a checkbox ever have the value `null`, it should always return a string ?

Comment: And yes, there are at least somewhat efficient ways to write such code, using a common selector and `Array.some` etc.

Comment: @adeneo There are no checkboxes, only textboxes.

Comment: @adeneo You mean, store all values in an array and go from there?

Comment: Typo, I meant textboxes, same thing really

Comment: @VadzimSavenok OK, then why would a text box ever have the value `null` as opposed to an empty string?

Comment: @vlaz Not null necessarily, just does not have a value, since I do not put input in it.

Comment: `[...values].some( val => val === null )`

Comment: `[].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('.textbox') ).some( el => el.value === "" )` etc

Comment: Do like `[...element.querySelectorAll(selector)].filter(e => e.value === null).length === 1 ? doThis() : doThat()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.reduce`:

```
var nonEmpty = [val1, val2, val3].reduce(((c, v) => c += (v !== "")), 0);
if (nonEmpty === 1) {
  // exactly one is not empty
}
```

Any other way of counting the non-empty inputs and checking that the count is equal to 1 would work too of course.

What that `.reduce()` code does is use an "arrow function" that increments a counter (`c`) when a value is not the empty string. (If you want to check for null, you can do that instead of course.) You could use a plain old-fashioned function too:

```
var nonEmpty = [val1, val2, val3].reduce(function(c, v) {
  return c += (v !== "");
}, 0);
```

The `.reduce()` function is passed 2 parameters: that callback function, and the initial value of `c` (zero in this case). The return value will be the *final* value of `c` returned by the last call to the callback.

Comment: I believe that might be exactly what I need. Can you please briefly explain the logic inside reduce method, so I can get the idea of properly using it.

Comment: @VadzimSavenok yes I will extend the answer

Answer (score 2):

just keep in th array values not null and then count how many remains :

```
var arr = ["hello", "", ""];

var result = arr.filter(x => x !== "").length;

if (result === 1) console.log("exactly one is not empty");
```

Comment: It is partially of what I need, but I also need to make sure EXACTLY ONE element is not empty. In your case, it sounds AT LEAST ONE element is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly check the textboxes for the values. If you are working in razor means you can use Jquery. Also this solution will work for any number of textboxes.

```js
 var count=0;
 var isExactlyOneNotEmpty= 
    function(){
    $('input[name="text[]"]').each(function() {
        if($(this).val()!="")
        {
          ++count;
        }
    });
    if(count==1)
    return true
    else
    return false;
    }
 var check=isExactlyOneNotEmpty();
 alert(check);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1" name="text[]">
<input type="text" id="text2" name="text[]" value="test">
<input type="text" id="text3" name="text[]">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Exclusive OR (XOR)` operator for that. Let's see what we can get with it:

[image]

However, the only result that doesn't fit your need is the last one (it returns `true` when all of them are also `true`).

To solve that, you could check if all values are not true at the same time. Summarizing, this expression does the trick:

`if( !(val1 && val2 && val3) && (val1^val2^val3) )`

Comment: It is good for small values, but if number grows to 10 or 20, it becomes a long line.

Comment: You're right, I've missed the "regardless of how many textboxes" part

Comment: I still appreciate this answer because I was looking explicitly for a small number. +1